# How to align 3 columns with max-widths in the center of row using bootstrap3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure how to move forward with this problem. I'm trying to simply align 3 columns that have explicit max-widths in the center of a row. Here's my code, and I'm using bootstrap3:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h4>box 1</h4>
      <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h4>box 2</h4>
      <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <h4>box 3</h4>
      <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

If I didn't have explicit max-widths, then the problem isn't *as* difficult since the width is always responsive, and I could just leave those empty column placeholders. In any case, I do need to have the max-width in place.

Comment: Your question seems bit confusing just share screenshot of layout so we can help.

Comment: Post the code you're using to make them max-width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check out flex box ?

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

remove your first and last divs ( col-sm-2 and col-sm-1 )

( i just added color to distinguish the columns and the `max-width` is just for the sake of the demo )

```css
.row{
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
}

.row div{
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">           
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:red;">
                <h4>box 1</h4>
                <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:green;">
                <h4>box 2</h4>
                <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-3" style="background:lightblue;">
                <h4>box 3</h4>
                <p>some text dfgdfgdfgdfg</p>                        
            </div>

        </div>
</div>
```